# Sql string to date Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have inserted a field with a format like this **'Jul 08, 2019 (10:57 AM)'**.

now i want to compare dates but this is a string datatype not date, i tried to convert it to date before comparing with date, it fails and gives error i tried Convert function and Cast function

`CONVERT(date, 'Jul 08, 2019 (10:57 AM)')`
`Cast('Jul 08, 2019 (10:57 AM)' as date)`

is there any way to convert it or to compare it with date like this format **'MM/DD/YYYY'**

Comment: `CONVERT` supports [various styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles). This particular format isn't one of them, but you can manipulate the string first so it does match one of these formats (e.g. `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(REPLACE('Jul 08, 2019 (10:57 AM)', '(', ''), ')', ''), 100)`). Do try to change these values once and for all so all future queries can simply use `DATETIME` for comparison; do not keep this conversion around in queries.

Comment: I knew it was an issue with the parentheses but I didn’t know how to get red of them. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem are the parenthesis in time.  Remove them  like:

```
select convert(DATETIME,  REPLACE(REPLACE('Jul 08, 2019 (10:57 AM)',')',''),'(',''))
```

Answer (score 1):

The parens are throwing off the conversion.

```
SELECT 
FORMAT(CONVERT(date, REPLACE(REPLACE('Jul 08, 2019 (10:57) AM', '(', ''), ')', '')), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
,FORMAT(Cast(REPLACE(REPLACE('Jul 08, 2019 (10:57) AM', '(', ''), ')', '') as date), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
,CONVERT(date, REPLACE(REPLACE('Jul 08, 2019 (10:57) AM', '(', ''), ')', ''))
,Cast(REPLACE(REPLACE('Jul 08, 2019 (10:57) AM', '(', ''), ')', '') as date)
```

If you need the MM/DD/YYYY format the first two options will work. If you just need the date value for a comparison you can replace the parens.